# Electrical sheathing removal for pool light?

Tags: electrical

Can I remove the sheathing from the pool light junction box to the panel, to make it easier to pull through existing conduit?

Comment: I agree with the post below, why not buy the correct wet location type wire ?  And pull if there are problems with the wiring that is in place.

Answer (score 3):

ABSOLUTELY NOT!

You should not be using cable or cord for ANY wiring to and for a pool light, with the exception of wiring that is within a building or structure. An insulated green ground is mandatory. The only exception to this is the cord that comes factory attached to a wet-niche type underwater light (luminaire).

PLEASE read up on the codes involved with pool wiring, it is NOT a place you want to mess around or cut corners!

> **680.23 Underwater Luminaires**
>
> This section covers all luminaires installed below the normal water level >of the pool.
>
> **(F) Branch-Circuit Wiring.**
>
> **(1) Wiring Methods.**
>
> Branch-circuit wiring on the supply side of enclosures and junction
>   boxes connected to conduits run to wet-niche and no-niche luminaires,
>   and the field wiring compartments of dry-niche luminaires, shall be
>   installed using rigid metal conduit, intermediate metal conduit,
>   liquidtight flexible nonmetallic conduit, rigid polyvinyl chloride
>   conduit, or reinforced thermosetting resin conduit. Where installed on
>   buildings, electrical metallic tubing shall be permitted, and where
>   installed within buildings, electrical nonmetallic tubing, Type MC
>   cable, electrical metallic tubing, or Type AC cable shall be
>   permitted. In all cases, an insulated equipment grounding conductor
>   sized in accordance with Table 250.122 but not less than 12 AWG shall
>   be required.
>
> Exception: Where connecting to transformers for pool lights, liquidtight flexible metal conduit shall be permitted. The length
>   shall not exceed 1.8 m (6 ft) for any one length or exceed 3.0 m (10
>   ft) in total length used.
>
> **(2) Equipment Grounding.**
>
> Other than listed low-voltage luminaires not requiring grounding, all
>   through-wall lighting assemblies, wet-niche, dry-niche, or no-niche
>   luminaires shall be connected to an insulated copper equipment
>   grounding conductor installed with the circuit conductors. The
>   equipment grounding conductor shall be installed without joint or
>   splice except as permitted in (F)(2)(a) and (F)(2)(b). The equipment
>   grounding conductor shall be sized in accordance with Table 250.122
>   but shall not be smaller than 12 AWG.
>
> Exception: An equipment grounding conductor between the wiring chamber of the secondary winding of a transformer and a junction box
>   shall be sized in accordance with the overcurrent device in this
>   circuit.
>
> (a)   If more than one underwater luminaire is supplied by the same
>   branch circuit, the equipment grounding conductor, installed between
>   the junction boxes, transformer enclosures, or other enclosures in the
>   supply circuit to wet-niche luminaires, or between the field-wiring
>   compartments of dry-niche luminaires, shall be permitted to be
>   terminated on grounding terminals.
>
> (b)   If the underwater luminaire is supplied from a transformer,
>   ground-fault circuit interrupter, clock-operated switch, or a manual
>   snap switch that is located between the panelboard and a junction box
>   connected to the conduit that extends directly to the underwater
>   luminaire, the equipment grounding conductor shall be permitted to
>   terminate on grounding terminals on the transformer, ground-fault
>   circuit interrupter, clock-operated switch enclosure, or an outlet box
>   used to enclose a snap switch.

Comment: Thank you I was trying to look up the electrical codes for my situation but as you know, unless you know where to look and what your looking for when it comes to our book of codes it can be a nightmare.  What I was asking is I bought a 120v led pool light to replace my 12v old power sucking pool light. It came with a 50ft cord attached and I know that at least 4ft of it is wrapped around the light for servicing need after installation. I was wondering if that remaing wire could be unsheathed & those 3 wires be pulled through the existing conduit & wired to the gfci and then to my controller?

Comment: No William. The sheathing needs to remain on the cord that is attached to the light housing.

Comment: Being 12V is not the reason your old light sucks power.  It's because it is incandescent/halogen. 12V is a good thing and makes your pool safer.   You can get LED bulbs that will fit in your old housing and have the best of both worlds. This may also be the least expensive option.